# How to prevent anyone from knowing that some domains are in the same server?

Tags: domains, server, ip-address, privacy

I am using some dedicated server with lots of different IPs. Some domains are put on different IPs.

However, anyone can see that `domaina.com` is pointed to `ns1.myserver.com`.

How to prevent that?

Comment: Why do you care? This should not be a problem. Either way, the IP addresses being within a block assigned to a single entity will give some of it away as well as the registration information and a fairly long list of very crafty ways of knowing that sites are related. It will amaze you!

Comment: By using a cdn you could overcome this.

Answer (score 2):

Users, google and other major search engines are able to detect finger prints from a variety of methods. Simply adding a dedicated IP is not enough, especially if the IP is provided by the same IP block chain.

*To reduce the finger prints your site must use the following:*

- a different name server, or use one that is used by hundreds to thousands of customers, but note if you plan to increase sites the finger print may become more obvious when linking to one another.
- a different c class or [c/block IP address](https://moz.com/blog/ipv6-cblocks-and-seo)
- a different associated Analyics ID i.e `UA-XX123456-X`
- a different whois profile or hidden
- anything unique to one site to another

It should also be noted that users and machines can access history and caching servers that will reveal previous used values and settings. So simply changing the changing a site after it has been cached, indexed and so forth might be a worthless task because people can access the previous information, for example:

- Domain whois history
- IP history
- Site contents history via a caching service like wayback.

Comment: Two sites having the same nameservers does not give away any information. Domain registrars have millions of domains using their nameservers, there is no correlation to hosting.

Comment: Yes you are correct on that, but as you increase sites the finger print becomes more obvious, so its yes and no :) updated answer, thanks for the pointing  that out.

Answer (score 0):

As @Simon_Hayer notes, there's no good way to prevent this entirely. However, if it's just a nameserver thing, you could create a new nameserver, ns.domaina.com (with the same IP address as ns1.myserver.com) and use that as domaina.com's nameserver. Again, this might not solve the main problem, but it will at least solve the "nameserver problem" you describe.

Comment: That won't work, because you can just do a reverse DNS lookup of the IP and find the original nameserver. And there is no advantage to hiding the nameserver anyway.

Comment: You don't even need to do that. When you "WHOIS" a nameserver, it includes an IP address (as it must; otherwise, it would be fairly useless). I agree there's no good solution here, but I think I technically answered the OP's question.

Comment: Yes that's what a reverse lookup actually does.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I don't think that's actually true, since you can reverse DNS non-nameservers too, but only nameserver IP addresses show up in WHOIS. However, it's almost not worth arguing over.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm not understanding what your point is. All "reverse DNS" does is check the IP of every domain/nameserver to see if it matches the IP you put in. So if `ns.domaina.com` points to `1.2.3.4`, a reverse DNS service will check and see that `ns1.myserver.com` also resolves to that IP.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat It doesn't actually quite work that way. Reverse DNS uses the special in-addr.arpa domain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.arpa) for reverse lookup, and it's theoretically possible to have forward and reverse DNS not match, and it's even possible to have the WHOIS record for a nameserver, the forward DNS for that nameserver and the reverse DNS for that nameserver all not match (though it's terrible practise).